# How to create input text for date if user input yyyy then append - to the inputbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datepicker

I have date format in yyyy-mm-dd, I want to let user to input date if user give 2000 then append -  to the date accordingly.

I have datepicker to provide date.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery use formatDate. [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

```
$.datepicker.formatDate( "yy-mm-dd", date );
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        How to get input type date
        in dd-mm-yyyy format ?
    </title>
    
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>DateInput</h1>
    
    <h3>
        Get input date in
        dd-mm-yyyy format
    </h3>
    
    <label for="start">
        Enter the Date:
    </label>

    <input type="date" name="begin"
        placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value=""
        min="1997-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This works @Rahul but what I want is input type text and I am loading datepicker using faltpickr.js

Comment: If user input yyyy then append - to the input text box

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this without using datepicker functions, thanks for the recommendations above!.

```
$("#ValidFrom").keyup(function () {
    var input = $("#ValidFrom");
    var len = $("#ValidFrom").val().length;
    alert(len);
    switch (len) {
        case 4: {
            input.val(input.val() + "-");
            break;
        }
        case 7: {
            input.val(input.val() + "-");

            break;
        }

        default: {
            break;
        }

    }

})
```